# how do I DRY out these jquery functions into one general function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Ive got a jquery app that has several grids (jqgrid) in defferent tabs.
Below ech grid I have a button:

```
<div id="content1" class="content">
    <table id="grid1" class="myGridClass"></table>
    <input id="ColChooser1"type = "button" value="Choose Columns" class="grid1"></input>
</div>

<div id="content2" class = "content">    
    <table id="grid2" class="myGridClass"></table>
    <input id="ColChooser2"type = "button" value = "Choose Columns" class="grid2"></input>
</div>
```

Ive got different functions for each of the column chooser buttons: example

```
$('#ColChooser1').click(function(){
  $('grid1').jqGrid('columnChooser');
};
```

Whats the best way to write one function for all the buttons?

so far this is what Ive got

```
$('div.content :input[value="Choose Columns"]').click(function{
   $('div.content table.'+this.attr('class')).jqGrid('columnChooser');
});
```

not sure if `this.attr('class')` will always be the same despite each button having the same class as its table element since jquery ui may add additional classes --

**Edited**
Below is what worked - close to the 1st answer below but tweaked a bit -

```
            $('div.DataContent :input[value="Choose Columns"]').click(function() {
                $(this).parent().find('.myGridClass').jqGrid('columnChooser');
            });
```

used .find instead of .children to traverse deeper than 1st level (jqgrid nests the original table element deeper)
also used a more specific selector '.myGridClass' rather than 'table' because jqGrid adds several other table elements, making use of the 'table' not return the original one intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) page in the jQuery docs.  You should be able to use a combination of these functions (e.g. parent, parentsUntil, children) to select the elements you want.

e.g:

```
$('div.content :input[value="Choose Columns"]').click(function{
    $(this).parent().children('table').jqGrid('columnChooser');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can start with your button click event

```
$(':input[id^=ColChooser]').click(function(){
var $this = $(this); // button
// Get the table
var $tbl = $this.prev('table');
// Now you have your table, and button apply the grid
});
```

Comment: seems like this shd work but the jgGrid plugin adds a bunch of new elements nesting the original table element deep. prev only returns immediately preceding siblings

Comment: Does it insert <table> between the original table and the button? otherwise $(this).prev('table.myGridClass') should be used

Answer (score 0):

attach a click handler to the parent, for the inputs, then find the sibling table.

```
$(parent_container_of_divs).on('click', '.content > input',function(){
    $(this).sibling('table').jqGrid('columnChooser');
});
```

if these elements have more than those elements you provided, let's be more specific. add a click handler to the parent for `ColChooser` inputs, and find it's sibling `grid` table.

```
$(parent_container_of_divs).on('click', 'input[id^="ColChooser"]',function(){
    $(this).sibling('table[id^="grid"]').jqGrid('columnChooser');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $('div.DataContent :input[value="Choose Columns"]').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().find('.myGridClass').jqGrid('columnChooser');
        });
```

used .find instead of .children  in one of the answers submitted to traverse deeper than 1st level (jqgrid nests the original table element deeper) also used a more specific selector '.myGridClass' rather than 'table' because jqGrid adds several other table elements, making use of the 'table' not return the original one intended